# Calling properties of objects in an array

Tags: powershell, object

I am not sure if my terminology is correct, but I want to be able to create an array\list\hashtable of IP Address objects that store the IP address and the serial number of the device to be referenced later.  I currently have this, but am looking for recommendations:

```
$IPArray = [collections.arraylist](Get-Content <FilePath>})
$PCArray = @()

$PCInfo = foreach ($PCIP in $IPArray)
{
    #HN
    $PCHN = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($PCIP).hostname
    #SN
    $PCSN = $PCHN.split('\.')[0]

    $TempArray = [pscustomobject]@{
        "IP" = $PCIP
        "SN" = $PCSN}

    $PCArray += $TempArray
}
Clear-Host
$PCArray | Where IP -eq <IPofSN> | Select -ExpandProperty SN
```

This provides me with the SN of the device as I wanted and also allows me to display the `$PCInfo` array as a table, but how do I manipulate it to call it in this manner:

`$PCArray.$PCIP.SN` or `$PCArray.$PCIP.IP`

I just can't seem to figure out how to do it that way and the above attempt is as close as I was able to get using googlefu and threads on here.

Currently I am resolving the HN and SN in multiple workflows and would rather just resolve it once and store it in an Object/Array for future reference and to reduce repetitive actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a hashtable to store each custom object, then add each custom object to the table **with the IP as the entry key**:

```
$IPAddresses = Get-Content <FilePath>
$PCTable = @{}

foreach ($PCIP in $IPAddresses) {
    $PCHostname = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByAddress($PCIP).hostname
    $PCSerialNumber = $PCHostname.Split('.')[0]

    $PCTable[$PCIP] = [pscustomobject]@{
        "IP" = $PCIP
        "SN" = $PCSerialNumber
    }
}
```

Now you can access the serial number associated with a given IP by indexing into the hashtable:

```
$PCTable['10.10.10.123'].SN # gives you the SN value for the IP 10.10.10.123 (if present)
```

Comment: This worked!  Thank you for that.  I knew  I was close, I just couldn't figure out the syntax to get it working.

The only thing I would mention is that `$PCTable` will no longer output a table, but `$PCTable.values` will.  Thanks again!

Comment: @ThePostman That's exactly right. You can also get all the entries (including the associated key) with `$entries = $PCTable.GetEnumerator() |% {$_}` :)